# Fetch html page content into a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Just a small question here, that how do we get fetch the html content via ajax into a variable that I could use later.
Right now, I have a button on the click of which, I fetch another html page simply through `load` method as follows:
`$('#container').load('http://127.0.0.1/someUrl')`

I want to get the content into a `var` instead that I could at a later time use to append to the `dom` 
`$('#someContainer').append(someVar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var someVar;

$.get("http://127.0.0.1/someUrl",function(data){
   someVar = data;
});
```

I would use $.get instead for this

Comment: I am not sure why but I have been trying this and the data in `someVar` comes to be undefined

Comment: The variable will be undefined until the ajax call returns.  It's an asynchronous call

Comment: Go that just after I wrote this comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery/JavaScript, you can use AJAX if the file is on the same website:

```
var somevar;
$.get('myfile.html', null, function(data){
    // data will be the HTML
    somevar = data;
}, 'html');
```

If the file is from another website, you could try using JSONP, but I would recommend doing a local AJAX request to a PHP script and have PHP make a curl request to get the HTML instead. This will likely handle the request more efficiently and reliably than JSONP.

Comment: Do you have Firebug installed for the Firefox browser? This will allow you to watch the AJAX request and see what the response is for easy troubleshooting.